# Navigating through dynamic Object (json) in C#

Tags: c#, json.net

i'm getting a json from a HTTP GET request that looks like after parsing it with "NewtonSoft.Json":

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
```

Where responseString is :

```
{"name1":{"id":123456789,"name":"nickname","profileIconId":1114,"summonerLevel":30}}
```

As you see, the name changes everytime, and i was wondering how do I navigate through this like `data.name1.name` where name1 changes everytime.

And how do i do if the json looks like :

```
{"name1":{"id":123456789,"name":"nickname","profileIconId":1114,"summonerLevel":30},"name2":{"id":123456789,"name":"nickname","profileIconId":948,"summonerLevel":30}}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can deserialize to JObject instead of dynamic, which gives you access to handy properties such as `First` which allow you to walk down the object structure without knowing the property name, as well as iterate over the objects on `data` with a foreach loop, based on your edit.

Once you reach the desired level, you can then resolve the JObject into a strong type with the `ToObject` extension method.

Note that you'll need to include the `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` namespace.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

void Main()
{
    var responseString = "{\"name1\":{\"id\":123456789,\"name\":\"nickname\",\"profileIconId\":1114,\"summonerLevel\":30},\"name2\":{\"id\":123456789,\"name\":\"nickname\",\"profileIconId\":948,\"summonerLevel\":30}}";
    JObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(responseString);
    var names = new List<Name>();

    foreach (var x in data) names.Add(x.Value.ToObject<Name>());
    names.Dump();
}

public class Name
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int profileIconId { get; set; }
    public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
}
```

If you prefer `LINQ`, you can always retrieve the values per the `Values()` method on the `JObject` and select each member.

```
var names = data.Values().Select(x => x.ToObject<Name>()).ToList();
```

This results in the following collection of `Name` objects.

[image]

Comment: Oh nice one i'll check it out !

Comment: Thank you for the time you spent to help me :D